# How can I prevent iOS from automatically underlining numbers in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a side project to play around with iOS development and decided it would be a messaging app. I'm adding timestamps to the messages below the message body, but still within the bubble, as I like this look better than outside of the bubble. iOS automatically formats these numbers for inclusion in calendar. Is there a way to escape this formatting for JUST those numbers? I'd like to keep it for when users enter times and dates, as that's really useful.

Below is the block that's adding the message body, as well as a screenshot of what I'm referring to.

```
override func didPressSendButton(button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: NSDate!) {
    JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound()
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: date)
    let hour = components.hour
    var minutes = components.minute

    if minutes < 10 {
        var minutes = String(minutes)
        minutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
    }
    var newText = text + "\n\n \(hour):\(minutes)"
    var newMessage = JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderDisplayName, text: newText);
    messages += [newMessage]
    self.finishSendingMessage()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you’re using a third-party library for the message UI; whether you can do this is likely to depend on how customizable that library is. Can you provide a link?

Comment: Is that a screen shot of iMessage app or is that your own UI?

Comment: Lines 2-11 of your function should be replaced with use of an `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: Did you resolve this?  [I worked around it in the third-party library demo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X9oIj.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the dataDetector enabled, so it's detecting URLs, phone numbers, dates, and so on, and turning them into links.

Disable all or specific data detection, depending on your needs.

In your specific case, it sounds like you'd want to disable the `UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent` data detection.

**Update:**

Here's a possible answer.  Format the text so it doesn't appear to be a time.  It may be possible, for example, to use a unicode character for the `newText` colon which the data detector won't catch as a time.  Another option is to use a zero-width space to separate the hours with an 'invisible' character.

```
var newText = text + "\n\n \(hour)\u{200b}:\(minutes)" // zero-width space
```

**Update 2:**

I downloaded JSQMessage and tried this in the sample code.  A zero-width space before the colon does appear to work to avoid the time from being detected.

```
[[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:kJSQDemoAvatarIdSquires
                   senderDisplayName:kJSQDemoAvatarDisplayNameSquires
                                date:[NSDate distantPast]
                                text:@"It even has data detectors. You can call me tonight. My cell number is 123-456-7890. My website is www.hexedbits.com.\n\n9\u200b:41"],
```

[image]

Comment: That’ll disable the data detection for the entirety of the text, which is not what they’re after: “Is there a way to escape this formatting for JUST those numbers? **I'd like to keep it for when users enter times and dates**, as that's really useful.”

Comment: The problem is that data detection isn't based on a range, so Apple's capability is either on or off for the entire (attributed) string.  The OP could try opening a JSQMessage issue, and see if the maintainer knows of any way.  I didn't look at the source, but I did check the JSQMessage documentation, and it doesn't seem to support range-based data detection either.

Comment: @Noah But you gave me an idea, as to how to work around it... I've updated the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the updated answer doesn't work. iOS still detects the time and formats it. Good idea though!

Comment: @traviswingo I downloaded the JSQMessage project and changed one line in the demo.  It seems to work on iOS 8.4.  *The demo is written in Objective C, but the concept still should work in Swift.  You may want to check the unicode syntax, as I'm not up to speed with Swift.*

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks a lot. That's a really great and simple trick!

Answer (score 3):

In the JSQMessagesViewController where the cell is getting created, the data detector type is set to all.

[Line 539 of JSQMessagesViewController.m](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/ddc20c96ee588b8e3a2bbcd0212f71249f1b58da/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesViewController.m#L539)

```
cell.textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll; 

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale; 
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES; 

return cell;
```

You can just set it to [UIDataDetectorTypeNone](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIDataDetectorTypes).

Comment: This works in the short-term, but long-term it also eliminates the ability of users to enter a time and date and have it automatically detected by iOS. I'd like to only disable this for this string of text. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3: To disable all detections

```
cell.textView?.dataDetectorTypes = []
```